# Kusto query get the X in each Y with max Z

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to write a Kusto query to get the [x] in each [y] with the most [z]. To be more specific, I'm querying the Azure Data Explorer sample table *Covid* to find the state with the most deaths in each country. I've tried this:

```
Covid19
| where State <> ""
| summarize deaths = max(Deaths) by State, Country
| project Country, State, deaths
| order by deaths
```

which runs, but produces multiple states from the same country. I also tried this:

```
Covid19
| where State <> ""
| summarize deaths = max(Deaths) by State, Country
| summarize deths = max(deaths) by State
| project Country, State, deths
```

But then I get an error on the last line "The name 'Country' does not refer to any known column...".

I also tried this:

```
Covid19
| where State <> ""
| summarize deaths = max(Deaths) by State, Country
| summarize deths = max(deaths) by Country
| project Country, deths
```

Which seems to produce correct results, but then I can't display the state. So it seems like I'm getting a runaround where I have either too much info or not enough.

Actual results from first query:

[image: Actual results]

Expected results:

[image: Expected Results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I can use arg_max for this, which I think is the simplest way to go

```
Covid19
| where isnotempty(State)
| summarize arg_max(Deaths, State) by Country
```

With specified output order:

```
Covid19
| where isnotempty(State)
| summarize arg_max(Deaths, State) by Country
| order by Deaths
| project Country, State, Deaths
```

Answer (score 3):

you could try using the `top-nested` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/topnestedoperator

```
Covid19
| where isnotempty(State)
| top-nested of Country by max(1), top-nested 1 of State by max(Deaths)
| project Country, State, deaths = aggregated_State
| order by deaths
```

or, if you want a more "natural"/"intuitive" syntax (as you've stated in your comment), you could use `arg_max()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction

```
Covid19
| where isnotempty(State)
| summarize arg_max(deaths, *) by Country
| order by deaths
```

Comment: Thanks Yoni, this does work but the syntax doesn't feel very natural. aggregated_State seems like a variable that is used but never declared - where does that come from?

Comment: i can't make it feel more natural for you :) i did, however, add another option that may (or may not) feel more natural to you

Comment: Thanks Yoni, your answers contain useful information. I found another example that I used for my final query. It uses arg_max and it pretty short and sweet. The advantage in my answer is it only uses one summarize statement